# Operations made by Conv2D in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

According to Pytorch documentation of Conv2D(c_in,c_out) (the other parameters are irrelevant for this question):

- **c_in** is the number of channels of the input image.
- **c_out** is the number of channel produced by the  convolution layer

What I don't understand is how many kernels/filters there are. In many post I have seen that **c_out** is indeed the number of kernels and that would mean that if  I have an input image of 3 channels, and I set **c_out=10**, the output would be 30 channels, but in reality I get 10 channels.

Answer (score 0):

A convolution operation is performed by "sliding" a kernel over the input, and computing the correlation between the kernel and the corresponding input. This computation yields a *single* scalar number for each "window".
Therefore, if you have an input with a shape `c_in`x`h`x`w`, a single kernel has `c_in`x`k_h`x`k_w` parameters. Sliding this kernel over the input will yield an output of shape `1`x`h`x`w` (assuming proper padding). As you can see, the number of input channels, `c_in`, does not affect the output shape, but rather the size of the *kernel*. Consequently, if you want to have `c_out` output channels, you need to have `c_out` filters each with a shape `c_in`x`h`x`w`.